# Non UTF8 chars in function parameters

Tags: postgresql

I have a badly behaved client application that is sending non UTF8 characters in a sql string to postgres. The string is in the form

```
"select call_function('paramvalue_1', paramvalue_2')"
```

the function looking like:

```
create or replace function(parameter_1 text, parameter_2 text)
returns...
```

Unfortunately the client occasionaly sends dodgy characters in the function parameters.   It's going to be tricky to clean up the client app and I was wondering if there is any way for a function in a UTF-8 database to accept non-UTF8 characters and strip them from the param values before they get inserted anywhere.

I'm pretty convinced the answer is no but I thought it was worth asking here.

Comment: "dodgy characters". Details? Error messages?

Comment: You don't need them to answer the question.

Comment: Interesting viewpoint. I'm not playing guessing games; maybe someone else will.